# Extend Custom Adapter which was extended from ArrayAdapter<Connection>

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have this Adapter class(ItemListAdapter) to display item list. but in that view I have set position 0 item text as bold. Now I need to create a separate ItemResultsListAdapter but in that I don't need to set position 0 element as bold. It should be normal.

I need to create `ItemResultsListAdapter` extending `ItemListAdapter`. Please help me to do this.

This is ItemListAdapter

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

private List<Items> items;
private final Context context;

public ItemListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Items> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);

    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

    if(items.get(position).getCategory().equals("COMPANY")) {
        textView.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    } else {
        textView.setText(items.get(position).getFirst_name() + " "
                + items.get(position).getLast_name());
    }

    if (position == 0) {
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }

    return rowView;
}
}
```

I need to extend this class and create ItemResultsListAdapter.

Comment: why you make separate adapter? use same adapter class, just pass one more parameter  to constructor in which you set true or false to make text bold simple..

Answer (score 0):

The reason why did I need to do is to **reduce code duplication**. This is the final solution that I found.

```
public class ItemResultsAdapter extends ItemListAdapter {

public ItemResultsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull   List<Items> items) {
    super(context, items);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
    if (position == 0) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.connection_name);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
    return rowView;
 }
}
```